# Symfony app_dev.php is working but production it is redirect to localhost

Tags: php, apache, symfony, virtualhost

I newer for symfony. I create a project named abc using symfony. I have create virtualhost for that project.

This is my virtualhost.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName abc.dev
    DocumentRoot /home/dinuka/workspace/abc/web 

    <Directory /home/dinuka/workspace/abc/web>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

When i use `localhost/abc/app.php` it is works fine. But i use `abc.dev/app.php` it just forword to `localhost`. I can use `abc.dev/app_dev.php` as well. I have clear all cache.

What is the issue?

Comment: you mean `app.php`? there's no `app.dev` inside `symfony2`, only `app.php` and `app_dev.php`

Comment: I do not think that it is a symfony problem. It looks like an issue on your apache. You should make a search on google about how to configure virtual hosts because there a few steps to verify.

Comment: Check inside app_dev.php script, by default not accepted connection outside localhost or 127.0.0.1. There are few lines of code that perform this.

Answer (score 0):

This is an Apache configuration issue, not related to Symfony.

**First of all:** are you including in your `/etc/hosts` file (in case you are on a Linux/MacOS box) an entry to resolve abc.dev to 127.0.0.1?

On the other hand, you are not defining a DirectoryIndex, I paste you a basic configuration for a Symfony project, hope it works for you:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName      abc.dev
    ServerAlias     www.abc.dev

    DocumentRoot    "/home/dinuka/workspace/abc/web"
    DirectoryIndex  app.php

    <Directory "/home/dinuka/workspace/abc/web">
        AllowOverride None
        Allow from All

        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            Options -MultiViews
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Yes. I used your vhost. My etc/hosts file also correct. But it not working.

Comment: Did you see Apache logs? Take a look after try to load your web, maybe you find a clue

Comment: You have a default virtual host configured? It would be a good idea to disable it (at least since you solve your problem)